# validate uniqueness not working as expected in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form on my view. I'm wanting to compare whats already inside the database against whats about to be put into the database.

Here is what i have in the controller

```
validate_uniqueness_of :link1, :link2, :link3, :link4
```

However when i try and run the create, i get this error

```
undefined method `validate_uniqueness_of'
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

I have also tried validates: and it didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

[`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) 
is an [ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods) method, you should move this validation from controller to model.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `validate_uniqueness_of'

You have a typo. It should be `validates_uniqueness_of` not `validate_uniqueness_of`

```
validates_uniqueness_of :link1, :link2, :link3, :link4
```

Also you should put this in the ***model*** not in the ***controller***

Answer (score 0):

As others have said validations should be in your model. For example:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :link1, :link2, :link3, :link4, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: Hi, This works lovely however i get the horrid rails page, How can i fix this to just show a plash message on the same page of the links that already exist?